# trigger in oracle that ensures that the value of ExpDate from the table ExpIt is less than or equal to the ERSubDate from the ExpReport

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a trigger in oracle that ensures that the value of `ExpDate` from the table `ExpIt` is less than or equal to the `ERSubDate` from the `ExpReport` on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements that change the `ExpDate` in the `ExpIt` table.

When ran in the command prompt, the following comes up

```
warning:  Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Here is what I have tried so far, where am I going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Expense_Date

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ExpDate
ON ExpIt
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    anExpDate ExpIts.ExpDate%TYPE;
    anERSubDate ExpReport.ERSubDate%TYPE;
    DateError EXCEPTION;
    ExMessage VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
   SELECT ExpDate, ERSubDate
     INTO anExpDate, anERSubDate
     FROM ExpIt, ExpReport
     WHERE ExpIt.ExpDate = :NEW.ExpDate;

   IF anExpDate <= anERSubDate THEN
      RAISE DateError;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DateError THEN
   
     ExMessage := ExMessage || 'Expense Date is Incorrect as it is after the Expense Report Submition date' || 
              to_date(anExpDate);
     raise_application_error(-20001, ExMessage);
END;
/
```

Comment: You've tagged this for both MySQL and Oracle.  Which database are you actually using?  Your syntax appears to be for Oracle.  If you are using Oracle, assuming you're using `SQL*Plus`, type `show errors` to see a list of the syntax errors.

Comment: You didn't join `ExpIt` and `ExpReport` table, so after successfull compilation on insert or update you will have another error: `ORA-01422: Too many rows` (assuming you have not single-row table `ExpReport`). So to prevent you from asking another question, you should specify (in `JOIN` clause, not `WHERE`) the condition on what you should combine data from both the tables.

Comment: Also there's a strange selection condition: you try to get the data, where updated date have the same value, as new value. Interesting assumption on update. And this trigger will allow you to put dates beyond the report date if you insert a new data, because you do not check new date alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you go too far down this track - be aware that you generally cannot access the table you are triggering on from within the trigger itself.

In your case, your trigger is on EXPIT and you want to query EXPIT.  That won't work.

Here's a trivial example of that:

```
SQL> create table t (x int );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger TRG
  3  before insert on T
  4  for each row
  5  declare
  6    blah int;
  7  begin
  8    select count(*) into blah from t;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (2);

1 row created.
```

It *looks* fine, but in reality, there are plenty of cases where it will NOT work

```
SQL> insert into t
  2  select rownum from dual
  3  connect by level <= 5;
insert into t
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table MCDONAC.T is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.TRG", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MCDONAC.TRG'
```

This is a big topic, and more details on the issue and how to work around it are here

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?file=MutatingTable.html#presentation-downloads-reg